# React state emptied out between calls in callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, state

I have this function:

```
addMessages(productId) {
    const msg = "Some message about product: " + productId;
    const newMessages = [...this.state.messages, msg];
    console.log(this.state.messages);
    this.setState({messages: newMessages}, function () {
        console.log(newMessages);
        console.log(this.state.messages);
    });
}
```

And I call it twice

```
for (i = 700; i <= 701, i++) {
    addMessages(i);
}
```

And I get this output:

```
[]
[]
["Some message about product: 700"]
["Some message about product: 701"]
["Some message about product: 701"]
["Some message about product: 701"]
```

Does anyone know why my state is acting so weird? I understand initially it is an empty array and that it runs through the first console log statement twice before it has a chance to go inside the callback function. But why is my state not getting 700? And why is it getting emptied out between the calls?

Comment: From where do you call your function? Can you maybe provide a codesandbox to reproduce that issue? Or just edit this one: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-chaplygin-3hq97)

Comment: It would run for 700 and 701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats happening is due to `setState` being asynchronous and react batching state updates. [React docs about `setState` batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

The two `console.log`'s outside of the `setState` callback are being executed immediately during the loop. Then the next two are coming from the first `setState` callback, and the last two are coming from the second `setState` callback.

The reason their outputs seem odd is because `newMessages` is actually different each time, but `this.state.messages` has already been updated in **both** callbacks. The reason for this is due to how react batches state updates. To illustrate this, you could console log inside the `render` function and see that react has only triggered 1 re-render for 2 state updates.

In summary, React is batching your `setStates`, and both callbacks are being executed after all of your looped updates have taken place.

**Also Note:** Since you are creating your new state array based on previous values, you should use the updater form of `setState`. As it is currently, `this.state.messages` will be an empty array for every iteration. The updater form guarantees that you will be using the most recent copy of state to update with.

Try this instead of creating `newMessages` outside the update call:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({ messages: [...prevState.messages, msg] }), /*callback*/ )
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, wouldn't you expect the last console log statement in the second iteration to have both strings in the array - ```["Some message about product: 700", "Some message about product: 701"]```

Comment: No, because you're using `...this.state.messages` to build the array. And since they are batched, `this.state.messages` is `[]` for both iterations. I'll give an example of how it fix it in my answer

Comment: Aha! That makes sense.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked; thank you very much! I've never heard about this before and I've seen and used my piece of code everywhere. Interesting though.